# Junit testing for a function

Tags: java, mockito

I have a confusion regarding Junit testing.For some functions(add function) with closed business logic we can make unit testing by asserting the function.

For example

```
public int add(int a,int b){
  int c = a+b;
  return c;
}
```

But for some function(as below example) in a route what methodology we have to do.

For example

```
public int foo(int totalnum){
  Zoo soo = new Zoo();
  int giraffNumber = soo.giraffe(totalnum);//here we are calling another method
  return giraffNumber;
}
```

For these kind of methods what approach we have to do.Does we need to write another class.

Can anybody please advise me with an example.

Comment: You have some choices.  Either include Zoo in the system under test, or do some mocking.  You might want to refactor this code if you want to mock `soo` with Mockito.  Take a look at [my article on mocking object creation](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/wiki/Mocking-Object-Creation) on the Mockito wiki.

Answer (score 2):

Ideally you turn that local variable into a field of your class. Or, probably not a Zoo object, but a factory for Zoo objects.

This factor gets inserted via dependency injection. And now you can use a mocking framework such as Mockito to have the factory instance return a mocked Zoo object.

That is you gain control over such objects. The key thing is to *not* call *new* for business logic objects.

Answer (score 1):

The dogmatic approach to unit testing is that you have to test only one thing at a time, which means that you are not allowed to use `new` in code to be tested, because this necessarily creates one more thing in addition to the thing that you have set out to test.

The way around this problem is *Dependency Injection*.  This means that instead of your code reaching out there to fetch its dependencies, (an example of which is using `new` to create a class that your code wants to use,) your code is supplied its dependencies from the outside.

So, in the case of `foo()`, that would mean either passing an instance of `Zoo` as a parameter to `foo()`, or, better yet, passing a `Zoo` factory as a constructor parameter to the class that contains `foo()`, so that then `foo()` can invoke the factory to obtain an instance of `Zoo`.

This way, you can pass a specially made implementation of `Zoo` to use for testing, such as one created with the help of `mockito`.

Of course, there is also the non-dogmatic approach to unit testing, which says that you should view each thing to be tested as a black box, and not worry about how it is implemented, and instead only worry about obtaining the correct result for a certain input.  And then there are those who point out that this is not unit testing, but integration testing.  And then there is the realization that there is no such thing as unit testing, only integration testing.  But by now we have entered the realm of philosophy.